# pandas - DataError no numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the mean across multiple columns using `groupby`.  Below is a toy example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['dell', 'microsoft', 'toshiba', 'apple'], 
'measure': ['sales', 'speed', 'wait time', 'service'], 'category': ['laptop', 
'tablet', 'smartphone', 'desktop'], '10/6/2015': [234, 333, 456, 290], 
'10/13/2015': [134, 154, 123, 177], '10/20/2015': [57, 57, 63, 71]})
```

I would like to calculate the average for each row across the date columns in `df`.  I figured that the best way to use `groupby` would be to change the column names so that they are non-unique for each month, like so:

```
def maybe_rename(col_name):
if re.match('\\d+/\\d+/\\d+', col_name):
    return re.split('/', col_name)[0] + re.split('/', col_name)[2]
else:
    return col_name

df = df.rename(columns = maybe_rename)

df

     company    measure    category  102015  102015  102015
0       dell      sales      laptop     234     134      57
1  microsoft      speed      tablet     333     154      57
2    toshiba  wait time  smartphone     456     123      63
3      apple    service     desktop     290     177      71
```

Then I tried to compute the `mean` like so:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis = 1).mean()
```

Which returned the following error: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

How do I get around this?  My desired result is below:

```
df

     company    measure    category  102015
0       dell      sales      laptop  141.66
1  microsoft      speed      tablet  181.33
2    toshiba  wait time  smartphone   214.0
3      apple    service     desktop   79.33
```

Comment: You can't take a mean on categorical values... exclude them first, do `df.loc[:,'102015'].mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @yatu what if there are a lot of columns though?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['dell', 'microsoft', 'toshiba', 'apple'],
'measure': ['sales', 'speed', 'wait time', 'service'], 'category': ['laptop',
'tablet', 'smartphone', 'desktop'], '10/6/2015': [234, 333, 456, 290],
'10/13/2015': [134, 154, 123, 177], '10/20/2015': [57, 57, 63, 71]})

columns_to_average = ['10/6/2015','10/20/2015','10/13/2015']
df['means'] = df[columns_to_average].mean(axis=1)
```

I would suggest transforming it into time series data if you have many date columns...

```
tdf = df[['category','10/6/2015','10/20/2015','10/13/2015']].transpose()
tdf = tdf.rename(columns=tdf.iloc[0]).drop(tdf.index[0])
print(tdf['laptop'].mean())
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be generalized to, say, n columns though.